# Print Biggest-Smallest in Python 3.4

Tags: python

I am learning Python and this is from a Udacity Course that I love, "Intro to computer science though Python". My attempt here:

```
def biggest(x,y,z):
    max = x
    if y>max:
        max = y
    if  z>max:
        max = z
    return max

def smallest(x,y,z):
    min = x
    if y<min:
        min = y
        if z<min:
            min = z
    return min

def set_range(x,y,z):
    result==biggest-smallest
    return result


print set_range(10, 4, 7)
```

I get an error message:

```
"line 18, in set_range
    result=biggest-smallest
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'function' and 'function'"
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Looks like you need to brush up on assignment (`=` rather than `==`) and calling functions.

Comment: You are testing equality instead of assiging and never calling the functions which also involves passing x y and z `result = biggest(x,y,z)-smallest(x,y,z)`

Comment: You cant subtract two functions. What you need to do is read the return values of `biggest` and `smallest` from your functions inside `result`

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that that entire code could be refactored to `my_numbers = [10, 4, 7]`, `print max(my_numbers) - min(my_numbers)`.

Comment: @Jesuisme, probably because the question is basically "here's my code, here's the error, go."

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks for clarifying; although in this case it seems like the OP is trying to learn the language and working through examples, instead of "do my homework for me" or "help me not get fired"

Comment: @Jesuisme, that's perfectly true, but it doesn't make a code+traceback dump a good question.

Answer (score 1):

I have no ideas why you have the same functions twice but you need to actually call the functions, pass the parameters and use `=` for assigning not `==` for equality:

```
def biggest(x, y, z):
    mx = x 
    if y > mx:
        mx = y
    if z > mx:
        mx = z
    return mx    

def smallest(x, y, z):
    mn = x
    if y < mn:
        mn = y
    if z < mn:
        mn = z
    return mn


def set_range(x, y, z):
    # use  "=" for assignment not  "==" for equality
    result = biggest(x, y, z) - smallest(x, y, z)
    return result

print set_range(10, 4, 7)
```

`==` is used it you want to test if two values are equal ie `1 == 1` , a single `=` is for when you want to assign a name to a variable i.e `foo = 1`.

Also best to avoid shadowing the builtin max and min functions so I changed the names in your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some corrections

```
def biggest(x,y,z):
    max = x
    if y>max:
        max = y
    if  z>max:
        max = z
    return max

def smallest(x,y,z):
    min = x
    if y<min:
        min = y
        if z<min:
            min = z
    return min

def set_range(x,y,z):
    big = biggest(x,y,z) #assign the function result to a variable
    small = smallest(x,y,z) #also let it inherit the inputs
    result = big - small
    print big
    print small
    return result


print set_range(10, 4, 7)
```